# Soundcloud API: Can I specify my request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, api, soundcloud

I want to get a list of all tracks - resp. the IDs of those tracks - from a certain user. So I'm sending following request to the API (JavaSript SDK):

```
callPath = "/users/3817541/tracks";

SC.get(callPath,function(obj)
{
    console.log(obj);
});
```

What I get back is an Array of Objects, each of them stuffed with all the track's detail out of which i can extract the IDs - but the transmission of all the unnecessary data slows down my application (I'm actually running this request for multiple users).

Is there any way to tell the API to return just a specific property (ID) of every object instead of the whole cake?

Comment: you could always parse the json data for id

Comment: yes, but since theres are a lot of tracks with a lot of information (while i actually only need the IDs) the request takes much longer than necessary. i edited my question to be more specific. thanks.

Comment: interesting, how much time does the request take?

Comment: around 100ms (running on localhost). thats for one user with 230 tracks. if i do that for 10'000 tracks it gets painful.